# Merge HSV channels under OpenCV 3 in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to split a HSV image into its channels, change them and them merge them back, however once I run the merge function the channels are interpreted as RBG channels, so for example for the following example I get a yellow image,

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_image)
s.fill(255)
v.fill(255)
hsv_image = cv2.merge([h, s, v])

cv2.imshow('example', hsv_image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

What is the proper way to do this in OpenCV 3 using Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Images are always displayed as they are BGR. If you want to show your HSV image, you need to convert to BGR first:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_image)
s.fill(255)
v.fill(255)
hsv_image = cv2.merge([h, s, v])

out = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imshow('example', out)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I had the wrong concept regarding how OpenCV manages the channels internally, it's working like a charm now!